# Spring LDAP Connection Pooling Not Working

Tags: spring, ldap, connection-pooling

I have an AXIS2 web service that uses Spring LDAP to accesses multiple directories.  It is running on Weblogic 10.3.6.  I am trying to use Spring Connection pooling to manage the ldap connections per ContextSource.  The application will deploy,run, return ldap data, but connection pooling is not working.  I had the ldap person check the directory logs and verify there is no pooling.  I can run a netstat -a | grep the connection and I see lots of TIME_WAIT entries.  I am wondering if the combination of jars is the issue or a possible configuration issue that is not allowing pooling to take affect. I verified all the jars below are in the build, the Weblogic java class path and in the AXIS2 WEB-INF/lib directory.  Any suggestions to solve this issue are 
appreciated.

Jar Files:
spring.jar (v2.5.6)
spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
commons-pool-1.6.jar

Spring application context file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:ldap="http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap.xsd">

<bean id="MyContextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.pool.factory.PoolingContextSource">
    <property name="contextSource" ref="ContextSourceTarget" />
    <property name="dirContextValidator"  ref="ContextValidator" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="false" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="false" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="5" />
    <property name="maxTotal" value="5" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="1" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="0" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="5000" />
    <property name="whenExhaustedAction" value="1" />
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="-1" />
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3" />
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis"  value="1800000" />
</bean> 

<bean id="ContextValidator"  class="org.springframework.ldap.pool.validation.DefaultDirContextValidator" >
</bean>

<bean id="ContextSourceTarget"  class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
    <property name="url" value="" />
    <property name="userDn" value="" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
    <property name="pooled" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="LdapTemplate"  class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="ContextSourceTarget" />
</bean>

<bean id="LdapDao" class="com.common.LdapDaoImpl">
    <property name="ldapTemplate" ref="LdapTemplate" />
</bean>
```